# dplyr passing variables to a function to dynamiclly arrange cols

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, tidyeval, quosure

I'm attempting to dynamically arrange a dataframe by passing a list of variable to use in ascending order first and one variable in descending order (last in the arranging order). each iteration selecting the top rows and storing another dataframe. 
The example below works when passing just the single descending variable, but I could not get it to work with the list of variables.

```
top_n_order <- function(df,n, expr_var, ... ){

  expr_var <- enquo(expr_var)
  dots <- list(...)
  expr_order <- enquos(...)

  if (!is_empty(dots)){
    arrange_call <- lazyeval::interp(~ list(x,desc(y)), x=expr_order, y=expr_var)

    selected_df <- df %>%
      arrange_(.dots = list(arrange_call)) %>%
      rownames_to_column("model_name") %>%
      select(mpg, cyl,  !! expr_var) %>%
      head(n)
    selected_df
  }else{
    selected_df <- df %>% 
      arrange(desc(!! expr_var)) %>%
      rownames_to_column("model_name") %>%
      select(model_name, mpg,cyl,  !! expr_var) %>%
      head(n)
    selected_df
  }

}

v_cols <- colnames(mtcars) 
cars_top_df <- data.frame()

top_n_order(mtcars, 5, as.name(v_cols[3]) )  ##Works


for(i in 1:length(v_cols)){
  v_order <- lapply(as.list(v_cols[-i]), as.name)
  tmp_selected <- top_n_order(mtcars, 5, as.name(v_cols[i]), v_order )  
  cars_top_df <- bind_rows(cars_top_df,tmp_selected)
}
cars_top_df %>%
  arrange(model_name)
```

Comment: I get error with your code.

Comment: It should work up to the line commented ## Works
The for loop - does give an error- thats my problem

Comment: Ok, thanks, not sure why we need `interp` here i.e. it could be done with `arrange_at`  Anyway, it is not very clear

Comment: We don't know what is `v_cols_suffix`, please try to make this post reproducible and show expected output. You can read  on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: fixed - thanks for the comment.